# how do i use reader in c# with mysql?

Tags: c#, mysql, reader

I have a remote mysql db and want to use the reader to display a single data inside a row with the id xx? i do have a functionally select which writes me all the data into a datagrid, but that is not what I want. I want to display a specific entry from a row into a label.

this is what I have

```
private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                string MyConnection2 = "datasource=172.105.76.212;port=3306;username=*****;password=*******";
                //Display query
                string Query = "select * from *database*.*datatable*;";
                MySqlConnection MyConn2 = new MySqlConnection(MyConnection2);
                MySqlCommand MyCommand2 = new MySqlCommand(Query, MyConn2);
                //  MyConn2.Open();
                //For offline connection we weill use  MySqlDataAdapter class.
                MySqlDataAdapter MyAdapter = new MySqlDataAdapter();
                MyAdapter.SelectCommand = MyCommand2;
                DataTable dTable = new DataTable();
                MyAdapter.Fill(dTable);
                dataGridView1.DataSource = dTable; // here i have assign dTable object to the  dataGridView1 object to display data.
                MyConn2.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }
```

can someone explain me how to use this sniplet to display a specific data aentry into a label?

I tried to use a reader section of a different code but this did not work and dont want to mix up different mysql connection aproach because it looks messy

Comment: please refer to: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/controls/how-to-manipulate-columns-in-the-windows-forms-datagridview-control?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8

Comment: Wouldn't `label.Text = dTable.Rows[0][1].ToString();` work? Where this would show from the first row the second field.

Comment: You need a binding source.  In following example a textbox in bind to the reader : https://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?887313-Binding-a-Data-Reader-in-Windows-Forms

Comment: problem is solved. thank you.

Comment: seeing "button_click" and "new MySqlConnection" in the same method....means you do not have a fundamental understanding of "layers". Please see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/data-access/introduction/ or internet-search "c# layers"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To display a specific entry from a row in a label, you can modify your existing code by adding a WHERE clause to your SQL query.

```
string MyConnection2 = "datasource=172.105.76.212;port=3306;username=*****;password=*******";
string Query = "SELECT column_name FROM database.table_name WHERE id = xx;";
MySqlConnection MyConn2 = new MySqlConnection(MyConnection2);
MySqlCommand MyCommand2 = new MySqlCommand(Query, MyConn2);

try
{
    MyConn2.Open();
    string result = MyCommand2.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
    label1.Text = result;
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
}
finally
{
    MyConn2.Close();
}
```

Comment: i have already solved this problem with the help of an answer to this. however i have further questions but can not post new questions anymore and i have no idea why. i am being blocked. however, thank you all for your generous help. i really aprechiate it.